# Rails does not recognize mime type when form submitted by javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following template, `delinquent_statuses.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Edit Delinquent Statuses</h2>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select#resident_id").change(function() {
        $("#unit_id").val(this.value);
        this.form.submit();
    });

    $("select#unit_id").change(function() {
        $("#resident_id").val(this.value);
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
</script>

<%= render partial: 'shared/tcpf_selector', locals: {ctrlr: 'leases', action: 'delinquent_statuses'} %>
<hr>

<%= form_with url: 'dq_get_delinquent', remote: true do |f| %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><%= f.label 'Name' %></td>
            <td><%= f.select(:resident_id, options_for_select(@resident_selects),
                             { include_blank: true, tabindex: 1, required: 'required'}) %></td>
            <td><%= f.label 'Apt #' %></td>
            <td><%= f.select(:unit_id, options_for_select(@unit_selects),
                             { include_blank: true, tabindex: 2}) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>

<div id="dq_selector_field">
</div>
```

The client wants the selectors for `@resident_selects` and `@unit_selects` to synch,so their values are the ids of a third associated model, `Lease`. In order to have the selectors synch, I need the javascript above.

The problem is, I can't get `respond_to` to recognize the format when I submit the form via js. The controller method looks like this (and I know there are other style issues with it, but one at a time):

```
  def dq_get_delinquent
    id = params.dig(:resident_id) || params.dig(:unit_id)
    @lease = Lease.find_by_id(id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lease.present?
        format.js
        format.json
      else
        redirect_to '/'
      end
    end
  end
```

But if I try to run this, I get the error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in LeasesController#dq_get_delinquent

I know js (and therefore, 'text/javascript') is not unknown, because other forms use it successfully. This is the only form I need to submit in this way, and I don't know how to supply `leases#dq_get_delinquent` with the information that it needs in order for it to know that I'm looking for the javascript template.

(I have tried using `render` to get `ds_get_delinquent` to display, but that replaces the whole page: not what I want.)

Anyone know of a way to satisfy `respond_to` from an non-Rails-generated form `submit()` event?

(UPDATE: I tried adding `request.format = :js`, and at least it recognizes the format, but now Rails just rewrites the screen and prints the interpolated `.js.erb` onto it.)

Comment: Did you try placing your above `<script>` tag after the `form`?

Comment: allenbrkn: that shouldn't work. But I gave it a try just for the heck of it, and it didn't work.